# How can I install Leiningen self-install from behind a firewall?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Is there a full download I can use which downloads leiningen and all related stuff in one go? I am not able to change the proxy settings on my local network, and this is the error I get:

"DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required."

## Update

You need to download the Leiningen standalone jar and then point LEIN_JAR to it:

```
 set LEIN_JAR=full path to leiningen standalone jar
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me - setting the proxies didn't work (and downloading the jar was unsatisfactory)

I got:

1. the [wget binary](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/gnuwin32/wget-1.11.4-1-bin.zip),  and
2. the [wget dependencies](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/gnuwin32/wget-1.11.4-1-dep.zip)

and put them on my PATH - ie `h:\util` contains:

```
wget.exe
libssl32.dll
libintl3.dll
libiconv2.dll
libeay32.dll
```

(where `H:\util` was already on my path. )

and then got a new terminal `cmd.exe` - and then `lein self-install` worked.

**Assumptions:**

- Downloading the jar was unsatisfactory because the point of `lein` is to be a dependency manager (like maven). You need to keep downloading stuff. If you manually download the first jar - then when you add some more jar dependencies to your project you'll have to manually download those as well. Might as well chuck out lein and go back to doing things on the Java classpath.
- In my view - in a windows environment proxy settings should be automatically detected. Lein can't do this (yet) - but the `wget` version I downloaded could. So you solve the problem of needing to explicitly specify the proxy. (In addition - manually setting the proxy just didn't work for me)

Comment: Could you expand a bit on this answer. I have upvoted it but don't quite understand what you mean?

Comment: I've expanded this some more

Comment: With the current [official project install script](https://leiningen.org/#install) provided, it may seem that the endorsed location of leiningen binaries is now https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/releases/

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/HTTP-Proxies

You should work on your googling skills ;)

Comment: My googling skills are terrible, I am the first to admit that! :)

Comment: This requires knowing the proxy username and password. Windows has no way of seeing the username and password

Comment: Most company proxies dont use username /password combinations, just http://someip:somespecialport . You should try to leave out username:password@

Comment: I tried using the Leiningen http_proxy and https_proxy settings with just somemeip:specialport which is the location of the proxy server but still get "Proxy Authentication Required" back

Answer (score 1):

I want to post this as a comment to @hawkeye, but I dont have enough reputation. This work for me only when I set environment variable.

```
set HTTP_CLIENT=wget --no-check-certificate -O
```